# How to delete a merge branch and squash commits

Tags: git

I'm having a hard time trying to squash these excessive commits.
When I run `git log --pretty=oneline`, the following items appear in the order below:

`e44e012 Merge branch 'branch A' of https://github.com/ into branch A
4176991 Commit D
767583f Commit C
f5a4c21 Commit B
83bb8e1 Commit A`

I want to squash these into one commit and get rid of the commit merge.  When I run `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, commits A-D appear, but the commit merge doesn't show up.  Any idea why? When I try running `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, I get commits A-D to appear along with some other commits, but the merge commit still doesn't show up as an option to squash.

`*   e44e012 Merge branch 'Branch A' of https://github.com/ into Branch A
|\
| * 767583f Commit C
| * f5a4c21 Commit B
| * 83bb8e1 Commit A
* | 4176991 Commit D
|/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101147/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-brosef).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101310/discussion-on-question-by-brosef-how-to-delete-a-merge-branch-and-squash-commits).

Answer (score 1):

Typing `git rebase -i HEAD~5` should show you a list like the following:

```
pick 83bb8e1 Commit A
pick f5a4c21 Commit B
pick 767583f Commit C
pick 4176991 Commit D
pick e44e012 Merge branch 'branch A' of https://github.com/ into branch A
```

Note carefully that the *oldest* commit will appear at the *top* of the list, which is the reverse order from what `git log` shows you.

If you want to squash the merge commit, along with commits B through D into commit A, then change the file to look like this:

```
pick 83bb8e1 Commit A
squash f5a4c21 Commit B
squash 767583f Commit C
squash 4176991 Commit D
squash e44e012 Merge branch 'branch A' of https://github.com/ into branch A
```

Save the file, close it, and then type `git rebase --continue` to finish the rebase.

Comment: i tried this, but the Merge branch doesn't appear for some reason.

Comment: Oh...do you want to retain the merge commit?